# Assuming that we have a very large struct occupying huge memory space when allocated

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm new to C (and structures in C). And I've seen varying code examples across the internet, but what is the benefit of doing this:

`void foo(LargeStruct* struct);`

instead of this

`void foo(LargeStruct struct);`

Does it make memory management easier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The former passes a pointer to the structure to the function. The latter makes a copy of the structure and passes it to the function. If the structure is large, making a copy of it for the function is expensive (uses lots of resources), so it should be avoided unless it's necessary.

Answer (score 5):

C passes `struct`s by value. What it means is that the function with the second signature would make a copy of the entire `LargeStruct` in order to pass it to `foo`. This is not economical in terms of memory use.

What's worse, the allocation of `LargeStruct` would happen in *automatic memory* (also known as "on the stack"). Depending on the actual size of your `struct`, the call may not be possible on some systems, because it would cause stack overflow.

The first approach, on the other hand, passes the `struct` by pointer. Pointer's size does not depend on the size of `LargeStruct`.

Comment: Should the first sentence be reworded, such as "C passes parameters by value"?

Comment: @FiddlingBits Not really: C makes an exception for arrays, which decay to pointers.

Answer (score 4):

Since C is passing arguments by value, there are two major points:

1. In function body, you will receive a copy of the parameter passed in, so in the case of `void foo(LargeStruct struct);`, you get a copy of the struct, when you modify the members of the struct, it's actually not seen outside, because it's a temporary copy, which is destroyed when the function returns. So if you want to modify a struct, you will have to pass in a pointer to that struct.
2. Since arguments are copied and if the struct is really large, there is some memory overhead. In this if you don't want to modify the struct, just to minimize the memory overhead, you can pass a const pointer:

   `foo(const LargeStruct *p);`